# Can dd copy raw data from hard drives when operating system cannot recognize file system of partitions of hard disks?

Tags: hard-drive, dd

As the title says, can dd copy down from hard disks even when operating system cannot recognize file system of partitions of hard disks?

Comment: When you access the raw device, you're bypassing the filesystem driver and reading the data directly from the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can.

Think of dd as a Xerox style copier which can copy pages despite not understanding the text written on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the reason dd is often used to create an exact copy of a faulty drive for further rescue attempts that won't cause further damage (and to have a backup copy).